# Can I create a reference to the value of an empty optional?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, stdoptional

I have seen the following pattern [several times](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter):

```
// T is a type, this is at namespace scope
std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> storage;
T &t = reinterpret_cast<T &>(storage);
```

This, coupled with adequate namespacing and naming, provides a pleasant interface (`t`) to users of the variable, while enabling deferred construction, reinitialization, etc of the actual object on the library side though placement `new` and explicit destructor calls. You can see it working [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a0da7f5db8a7259).

Now, `std::aligned_storage` is neat and all, but C++17 gave us a new tool in the box for such storage-vs-object lifetime splitting, that is `std::optional`.

However, the two ways of accessing the value of an `std::optional` (`value()` and `operator*`) both require a value to actually be there; otherwise `value()` will throw `std::bad_optional_access`, while `operator*` will trigger undefined behaviour (via breaking the *requires* clause in [[optional.observe]§5](http://eel.is/c++draft/optional.optional#optional.observe-5)).

```
std::optional<T> storage;
T &t = *storage; // Looks okay, mines bitcoin when you're not looking
```

Is such a usage of `std::optional` still possible somehow?
If not, what would be a reason for preventing it?

Comment: Doesn't using `t` safely in the first example requires running a bunch of bookkeeping related checks beforehand?

Comment: @StoryTeller it does require a bit of caution, but nothing that a dash of SBRM can't handle. Often the object is actually scoped to `main`, and it's just about avoiding doing too much stuff during static initialization/destruction while keeping the global access point.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `T &t = reinterpret_cast<T &>(storage);` exhibits undefined behavior - or rather, the subsequent use of `t` would. The right way to do it is `T& t = *new(&storage) T;`. That's essentially equivalent to setting the value in `std::optional`. So in the end, it's six of one, half a dozen of the other.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik this should be equivalent to the pointer juggling [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13466556/3233393), which apparently is fine.

Comment: From that question: *"I use placement new to create the object"*

Comment: @IgorTandetnik well, so do I?

Comment: Do you? It doesn't appear anywhere in the question, as far as I can tell. My point is, if you do that, then you could at the same spot assign a value to your `optional`, and then `operator*` would work.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik whoops, it was in the demo code but I forgot to add it to the question itself. That's fixed. But here the deal is to retrieve the pointer *before* the object gets constructed there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This, coupled with adequate namespacing and naming, provides a pleasant interface (t) to users of the variable, while enabling deferred construction, reinitialization, etc of the actual object on the library side.

Unfortunately, using `t` to access the object constructed later at that address is undefined behavior. This is one of the [reasons](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4303.html) why `std::launder` is proposed.

Note this case is different from the case described in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466556/aligned-storage-and-strict-aliasing). In that question, the reference/pointer is obtained **after** the object of type `T` is created (though [this may also be undefined](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/std-discussion/xaAwFR6qUmY) after C++17 without `std::launder`).

> Is such an usage of std::optional still possible somehow?

As what you pointed out, this is undefined behavior.

> If not, what would be a reason for preventing it?

An optimizer may find the address is associated with the object that provides storage for `T`, and ignore any access to that address through a glvalue of type that causes undefined behavior. In fact, the reasons are essentially [how strict-aliasing rules benefit an optimizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule/99010#99010).

Comment: Hmm, that's unfortunate. I suppose that `std::launder` wouldn't help since it should be added at every point of use?

Comment: @Quentin I'm afraid so.