# Getting pointer to contained object from std::aligned_union_t

Tags: c++

I want to construct using placement-new an object of arbitrary type inside a `std::aligned_union_t`. Once constructed successfully, I want to be able to get back the pointer to the constructed object without storing it separately. Is it legal to do so by simply `reinterpret_cast`'ing the `std::aligned_union_t`, as long as I ensure that I cast it to the original type that was constructed?

Is the following code that exemplifies the above, legal? Are there any type trait requirements that `MyStruct` should satisfy for it to be so? For instance, does it have to be a POD?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>
#include <cstddef>
#include <exception>

struct MyStruct
{
    int value = 0;
};

constexpr size_t c_alignedUnionSize = 10;
std::aligned_union_t<c_alignedUnionSize, std::max_align_t> g_storage;

MyStruct* GetPtr()
{
    return reinterpret_cast<MyStruct*>(std::addressof(g_storage));
}

void Construct()
{
    if (sizeof(MyStruct) > sizeof(g_storage))
    {
        std::terminate();
    }

    auto ptr = new (std::addressof(g_storage)) MyStruct{};
    if (!ptr)
    {
        std::terminate();
    }

    GetPtr()->value = 123;
}

void Destroy()
{
    GetPtr()->~MyStruct();
}

int GetValue()
{
    return GetPtr()->value;
}

int main()
{
    Construct();
    auto value = GetValue();
    Destroy();
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Related question: [Does reinterpret_casting std::aligned_storage* to T* without std::launder violate strict-aliasing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735657/does-reinterpret-casting-stdaligned-storage-to-t-without-stdlaunder-violat)

Answer (score 1):

`reinterpret_cast` here should be safe. The latest Standard draft says:

> [[expr.reinterpret.cast]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast)
>
> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type. When a prvalue `v` of object pointer type is converted to the object pointer type “pointer to cv `T`”, the result is `static_­cast<cv T*>(static_­cast<cv void*>(v))`. [ Note: Converting a prvalue of type “pointer to `T1`” to the type “pointer to `T2`” (where `T1` and `T2` are object types and where the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value. — end note ]

Related questions:

- [aligned_storage and strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466556/aligned-storage-and-strict-aliasing)

Comment: I think the question you link to is too old. A newer related question is: [Does this really break strict-aliasing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003727/does-this-really-break-strict-aliasing-rules)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is forbidden by the standard. In the C++ standard `reinterpret_cast` from one pointer to an object *a* to another object *b* of different type is stated to be valid only when the two object are *pointer interconvertible*, [[basic.compound]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#4):

> Two objects a and b are *pointer-interconvertible* if:
>
> - they are the same object, or
> - one is a union object and the other is a non-static data member of that object ([class.union]), or
> - one is a standard-layout class object and the other is the first non-static data member of that object, or, if the object has no non-static data members, the first base class subobject of that object ([class.mem]), or
> - there exists an object c such that a and c are pointer-interconvertible, and c and b are pointer-interconvertible.
>
> If two objects are pointer-interconvertible, then they have the same address, and it is possible to obtain a pointer to one from a pointer to the other via a `reinterpret_­cast`. [ Note: An array object and its first element are not pointer-interconvertible, even though they have the same address. — end note ]

The fact that a pointer has the right type and right value (memory address) does not make it a valid pointer. The canonical example of such surprising behavior is this:

```
alignas(int) unsigned char buff[2*sizeof(int)];
auto p1 = new(buff) int{};
auto p2 = new(buff+sizeof(int)) int{};
*(p1+1) = 10;//Undefined behavior
//p1+1 does not point to *p2 even if p1 and p2 have same type and value.
```

So, to be standard compliant, you must store the value of the pointer returned by `new`.

---

I found a good solution that consists to cast the pointer to an integer type and that to an other pointer type, that will cause an *implementation defined behavior* ([[expr.reinterpret_cast]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#5)):

```
reinterpret_cast<MyStruct*>(reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(addressof(g_storage));
```

Comment: *"If two objects are pointer-interconvertible, then they have the same address, and it is possible to obtain a pointer to one from a pointer to the other via a `reinterpret_­cast`."* Is there any place where the Standard explicitly mentions that `reinterpret_cast` **is** invalid between two non-interconvertible pointers?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo [\[intro.defs\],Undefined behavior](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.defs#defns.undefined) *[...] Undefined behavior may be expected when this document omits any explicit definition [...]*. The simple fact that the standard define the concept of *pointer interconvertibility* that is used explicitly to allow some `reinterpret_cast` from one pointer type to an other pointer, clearly says that other `reinterpret_cast` are not defined!

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Actualy the `reinterpret_cast` is always defined, but in situation not described by the standard, the result may be an [*invalid pointer value*](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3) => the pointer is not a pointer *to object*.